# Python 3.4- Inserting spaces at regular intervals

Tags: python

I am trying to get Python to allow me to insert a space at regular intervals (every 5th character), in a string.
This is my code:

```
str1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
list1 = []
list2 = []
count = 3
space = " "

# converting string to list
for i in str1:
    list1.append(i)
print(list1)

# inserting spaces
for i in list1:
    mod = count%6
    count = count + 1
    if mod == 0:
        list1.insert(count,space)
        count = count + 1
#converting back to a string
list2 = "".join(list1)
print(str(list2))
```

however it groups the first section together as 7. 
Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: `import textwrap; print(' '.join(textwrap.wrap("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)))`

Comment: Just use `" ".join(str1[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(str1), 5))`.  One of my highest scoring answers was for that one line.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy with a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'.{1,5}', str1))
'abcde fghij klmno pqrst uvwxy z'
```

Or use a slice:

```
>>> n=5
>>> ' '.join([str1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str1), n)])
'abcde fghij klmno pqrst uvwxy z'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a step by step script:

You can use the `string` module to get all the ascii letters in lowercase:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
```

Now, you can iterate every five characters and add a space using the following:

```
result = ""
for i in range(0,len(ascii_lowercase), 5):
    result += ascii_lowercase[i:i+5] + ' '
print(result)
```

Prints the following result:

```
abcde fghij klmno pqrst uvwxy z
```