# How to put space in a regular interval?

Tags: python, dictionary

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662526/python-3-4-inserting-spaces-at-regular-intervals).

Instead of populating the dictionary with a single number, I want to populate this with a string of numbers. I've got a long string of numbers separated at interval 7 by a comma.

I've got something like this,

```
values = '123456,789101,2345678' # (a string of numbers)

keys = [1,2,3]
```

I want to create a dictionary like something below:

```
my_dict = {1: '123456', 2: '789101', 3: '2345678'}
```

Comment: Does key always start at `1` and is strictly increasing with `1`?

Comment: `values` appears to be a tuple of integers, but you are saying it is a *string* of numbers? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Given that you responded to one of the answers with 'Works perfectly fine', I've updated both your input and your expected output to match the assumptions that answerer made (input is a string with digits and commas, output dictionary values are strings too).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> values = '123456,789101,2345678'
>>> 
>>> keys = [1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dict(zip(keys, values.split(',')))
{1: '123456', 2: '789101', 3: '2345678'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> values = '123456,789101,2345678'
>>> my_dict = {i+1:j for i,j in enumerate(values.split(','))}
```

**Outputs**

```
>>> print (my_dict) 
>>> {1: '123456', 2: '789101', 3: '2345678'}
```

Comment: `enumerate()` also has a `start` parameter, you could use this to avoid adding `1` each time.

Comment: Thanks for improving. But now vishes has a shorter way with enumurate so i'll just leave it like this for diversity

Comment: yeah!! Works perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: values = '123456,789101,2345678'

In [2]: dict(enumerate(values.split(','), 1))
Out[2]: {1: '123456', 2: '789101', 3: '2345678'}
```